# Authuenicate download for files on another server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise, download

I have a rails application running on a server. The Application has user authentication implemented using Devise. I have files hosted on another server, I want to be able to allow only authenticated (logged in) users within my application to download these files - is this possible? is there a nice Rails solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You are looking for a SSO mechanism.

> Required a single user manager app that can act as a Provider (OAuth2
>   ?) and different applications (or Clients) that can authenticate
>   themselves using this same user manager

See : http://codetheory.in/rails-devise-omniauth-sso/
Github : https://github.com/rishabhp/sso-rails-provider

Jeff

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18124456)

Comment: In the meantime, If the code is flawed and I put it as static here, No one will see the correction until he goes to the source.

I addedd the Github link as fallback.

The downvote is really hard and cheap.